# How do I make C-w behave the same as bash?

Tags: emacs, copy-paste, key-bindings

In bash when I press C-w it kills the word before the cursor. In emacs, it yanks the region but when there is no active region it kills forward. So I have to press M- to *(backward-kill-word)* How do I make C-w behave like the bash shell? Do I have to make a function to check for active region and then decide to kill either *(backwards-kill-word)* or *(kill-region)* or is there another way?

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: It is a programing related question as Editors are part of the parafernalia.

Comment: I'm asking because I genuinely don't know, but are these sorts of questions considered appropriate for this site? I've seen many questions of this nature closed before...

Comment: No idea if it is appropriate. It is on my mind, although SO is suffering from excessive moderation the last few years IMHO. But it reads like a normal emacs question to me. How do I make X or A mode for Y.

Comment: I understand, and share your opinion. I'll exit the conversation such that it can continue on-topic. Cheers. +1.

Comment: Now you made me doubt if perhaps it would better suited in SuperUser? Well I know that SO is not exclusively Programming Q&A (there is another stackexchange for that now) so maybe it is for Programing & Parafernalia?

Comment: This has been discussed repeatedly on Meta, and the last conclusion I saw was that Emacs questions asked on S.O. should be left here.

Comment: But is it "better filed" on SuperUser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my defuns.el (probably ripped from elsewhere):

```
(defun kill-region-or-backward-word ()
  "If the region is active and non-empty, call `kill-region'.
Otherwise, call `backward-kill-word'."
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively
   (if (use-region-p) 'kill-region 'backward-kill-word)))
```

Edit: tali713 on #emacs had this better version with call-interactively.

Answer (score 1):

You already answer your own question. Just write a few lines of elisp to do this or that depending on

```
(if mark-active
```